# java mysql nested search implementation

Tags: java, mysql, search, nested

I need to implement Nested Search (mean to say search records within previously searched records) using mysql/java code.
For example, First I searched a table with condition(firstname like '%abc%') and I got 1000 rows for that, Now I want to apply the new search condition (lastname like '%xyz%') on those 1000 rows only not for all rows in that table.

Can anyone let me know how to implement this?
Is there any feature provided by DB(mysql) itself for this?

**As i mentioned user applies second search on records received from first search result, it's not like user gives both the inputs simultaneously and Second search is not predictable it can be any search on any column.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

`select * from myTable where (firstname like '%abc%' AND lastname like '%xyz%'`)

or

`select * from myTable where firstname like '%abc%' AND lastname like '%xyz%'`

As I don't have mysql with me now, I can't check which one will work... BUT I think with bracket one will work...

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Parker:  Thanks for the quick reply but its not the answer I am looking for, As i mentioned user applies second search on records received from first search result, it's not like user gives both the inputs simultaneously and Second search is not predictable it can be any search on any column.

Comment: then you can compare inside java code whether last name contains xyz or not.... by using `myString.indexof("xyz")>=1`

Comment: can you explain your scenario with **example**? how you are doing this?? i don't think what you are doing is correct...

Comment: so basically User first search for A and got rows R1 and now searching for B on only on those R1 rows not on all the rows of that table.

Comment: is that you going to do one **ONE** page??

Comment: also i said with example... like i will accept first name on pageA and then go ahead to pageB where i will ask last name....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... FROM some_table WHERE firstname like '%abc%' AND lastname like '%xyz%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but its not the answer I am looking for, As i mentioned user applies second search on records received from first search result, it's not like user gives both the inputs simultaneously and Second search is not predictable it can be any search on any column.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly apply `AND` if you still want to go for subQuerwy

```
SELECT ID, NAME from TABLE_NAME WHERE fname like '%j%' AND ID IN 
( SELECT ID FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE lname like '%J%');
```

But for shake of simplicity you should go for `AND`

Comment: Thanks buddy, Please read the question again, I want to apply nested search means want to apply search on previously search results.

Comment: so basically User first search for A and got rows R1 and now searching for B on only on those R1 rows not on all the tables.

Comment: You can do it probably using Procedures